# Django database hung in migration

Tags: django, django-south

**EDIT: I solved the issue.  The problem was that I had a shell open with a database connection to that model.  I exited the shell, and everything continued.**

I just migrated my database with south, but rather than migrating one app, i accidentally migrated the whole project (`./manage.py migrate`). Everything went fine until it got to the app that needed the migration.  I didnt get an error, but it is hung at that point:

```
~/django/baeren $ ./manage.py migrate
Running migrations for home:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for home.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for price:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for price.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for gallery:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for gallery.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for menu:
 - Migrating forwards to 0006_auto__add_field_menu_category.
 > menu:0006_auto__add_field_menu_category
```

The site is still running, and everything is accessible on the admin page except for that specific model.  Is it ok to just kill the process and remigrate, or would I be risking something unrecoverable that I don't understand?  If the latter, is there an alternative route?

Comment: You should answer your own question if you solved it.

Comment: I didn't know that was allowed.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem for *postgresql* database.
After restarting *postgresql* database, it works fine.

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: This effectively has the same result as OP's solution (kill the client), since by killing the server (postgresql/mysql) you are terminating all client connections and starting fresh.